Is there a correction algorithm for Newton-Raphson method to find global minimum instead of local?
I have a case of single-variable function minimization where a "simple" Newton-Raphson algorithm works perfectly in most cases, except the edge case when the function has several local minima, where it breaks, because it finds a random local minimum (or even maximum) instead of the global one.
I'm aware that there are global optimization methods (swarm, annealing, etc), but most of them are much slower than Newton.
I'd rather prefer to employ some kind of detection-correction algorithm:

detect if several local minima/maxima exist (could be done by rerunning Newton with different initial conditions I suppose)
correct to global minimum.

Are you guys aware of any algorithm like that? Again, I'm dealing with a single-variable function, so it's a relatively simple problem, compared to the usual global optimization stuff.
Edit: my use case is ray tracing implicit surfaces, which I'm trying my hand at.
Here's an example of what I get with simple Newton (left) and with corrections (right):


nr by construction, when it finds a minimum doesn't continue looking for the minimum. You can try various heuristics, like running nr in parallel with many starting points, but there is no way to my knowledge to make it truly global

@user619894, thanks, I think I found a trick which works for my use case. It compares Newton and gradient descent steps and chooses whichever one is shorter. Don't know why that works, but it does.

Not sure what you mean by that, as gradient descent is effectively the multi-dimensional version of Newton-Raphson, but it has to be peculiar to your application, as gradient descent also finds local minimums, not global ones.
